# Invalid Argument Error Making Search Bar

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, variables

I'm making a search bar for a site it works in one page but the other one I keep getting invalid argument error. Hopefully everything that is needed is below. I am using codeigniter. Please help. Thanks.

//Doesnt Work//

```
private function getUsers () {
    $search = $this->input->post('search');

    if($search && filter_var($search, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $where = 'WHERE source_adusers.ad_Email="'.$search.'"';
    } else if ($search) {
        $where = "WHERE source_adusers.ad_account='".$search."'";
    } else if (!$search) {
        $where = '';
    }

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT *, COUNT(rollout_systems.EAM_USER) as systems FROM source_adusers 
        LEFT JOIN rollout_systems ON rollout_systems.EAM_User = source_adusers.ad_account '.$where.' GROUP BY source_adusers.ad_account LIMIT 0,50');

    $users = null;

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data['account'] = $row->ad_account;
        $data['email'] = $row->ad_Email;
        $data['name'] = $row->ad_DispName;
        $data['systems'] = $row->systems;

        $users[] = $data;
    }

    if(isset($this->data['users'])) {
        $this->data['users'] = $users;
    } else {
        $this->data['users'] = $users;
    }
}
```

//Does Work//

```
private function getSystems () {
    $search = $this->input->post('search');

    if ($search) {
        $where = 'WHERE disc_systempool.ad_name="'.$search.'"';
    } else {
        $where = '';
    }

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT *, COUNT(rollout_systems.sys_name) as scopes FROM disc_systempool LEFT JOIN rollout_systems 
        ON rollout_systems.sys_name=disc_systempool.ad_name '.$where.' GROUP BY disc_systempool.ad_name LIMIT 0,50');

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data['model'] = $row->eam_Model;
        $data['account'] = $row->ad_name;
        $data['city'] = $row->eam_City;
        $data['scopes'] = $row->scopes;
        $data['search'] = $this->input->post('search');

        $systems[] = $data;
    }

    if(isset($this->data['systems'])) {
        $this->data['systems'] = $systems;
    } else {
        $this->data['systems'] = $systems;
    }
}
```

//Where I'm getting the error//

```
<tbody>
    <? foreach ($users as $user) { ?>                      <---- Line 18
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><?=$user['account']?></td>
        <td><?=$user['name']?></td>
        <td><?=$user['email']?></td>
        <td class="center"><?=$user['systems']?></td>
        <td class="center"><a href="#">View Details</a></td>
    </tr>
    <? } ?>
</tbody>
```

//Error//

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: headquarters/users.php
Line Number: 18
```

Comment: Error is indicating that `$users` isn't set. What do you get if you `var_dump($users)` after the loop in your getusers method? My guess is the sql statement is not returning what you expect.

Comment: Im still getting the invalid argument error. what do you think is wrong with the sql?

Comment: Also I tested the SQL statement on the servers database and it worked.

Comment: After '$users[] = $data; }'. Make sure it is *outside* the loop. Then, when you load the page, you'll get to see what the array actually looks like.

Comment: Yeah. It says its null even though i copied a name from the list into the search bar. maybe it is the sql. any ideas?

Comment: Try a var_dump on $query->result(), before the loop

Comment: array(0) { } 

is what came up

Comment: Yeah, something's up with the SQL. Try adding $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); in your controller. This will show your SQL statement as CI tries to execute it. That should give you an idea of the issue if it is indeed a SQL issue.

Comment: hmm, it seems to work when i search an email address. But not an account.

Comment: This is what im getting when i search for an account.

SELECT *, COUNT(rollout_systems.EAM_USER) as systems FROM source_adusers 
            LEFT JOIN rollout_systems ON rollout_systems.EAM_User = source_adusers.ad_account WHERE source_adusers.ad_account="DNPE, Marketing" GROUP BY source_adusers.ad_account LIMIT 0,50

Comment: What happens if you execute this statement manually on your database?

Comment: It shows the right thing. I fixed the problem. I misunderstood what the guy that hired me asked me to do. He said search account name. I was search display name which kept giving me the error. Kinda feel stupid. all fixed now though. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: You're welcome. You might create an answer for that and accept it to close this question out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows the right thing. I fixed the problem. I misunderstood what the guy that hired me asked me to do. He said search account name. I was search display name which kept giving me the error.

Answer (score -1):

Try making a `var_dump($data);` inside your view. If empty. Do the same in your controller by just printing it out. If you see data inside the `$data` array. Make sure that you are sending the `$data` array with you into the view `$this->load->view("view",$data);`

Besides that, i might be wondering why you do foreach on your rows inside of the controller instead of just using the object right in your view

```
return $query->result();
```

in view

```
foreach($users as $user) { print $user->account; }
```

Hope you figure it out.
Best regards
Jonas

Comment: It shows the right thing. I fixed the problem. I misunderstood what the guy that hired me asked me to do. He said search account name. I was search display name which kept giving me the error. Kinda feel stupid. all fixed now though. Thanks for the help. :)